# How to evaluate a function at unequal interval in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to make a table in Mathematica using the following function

d1 = Table[f1[x], {x, xmin, xmax, xstep}];

which calculate function f1[x] from xmin to xmax in the step of xstep. This method will give me equal spacing. I on the other hand want this spacing to be logarithmic or non-linear. For eg. in the interval of 1 to 10, the numbers should be [1,1.2,2,3,6,10] or anything but not with an equal spacing which is the default. How can I do that?.

Answer (score 0):

This syntax uses the successive values

```
d1 = Table[f1[x], {x, {1, 1.2, 2, 3, 6, 10}}]
```

See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html

This could also be achieved by

```
d1 = f1 /@ {1, 1.2, 2, 3, 6, 10}
```

and with logs

```
d1 = f1 /@ N[Log /@ Range[10]]
```

Comment: Actually, I have a large data where writing the individual point will not be a good idea.  The problem is like say I want to make a table where I want to calculate the value of sin(x) for some x and x varies in a non-linear or logarithmic fashion. Should the last option be the best one in that case?